# Is there a CalDAV client library for Java?

Tags: java, calendar

I want to communicate using CalDAV protocol with my calendar server. Are there any supported Java client libraries for this?

Comment: This kind of Question may be posted on the sister site: [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

Try [CalDAV4j](http://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/)

Answer (score 4):

The Calendaring and Scheduling Consortium (CalConnect) has a [list of libraries and tools](https://devguide.calconnect.org/CalDAV/libraries/)

Answer (score 4):

I use, and contribute to, [ical4j-connector](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Connector). Use the source, I often make fixes or add new stuff to the connector while the snapshot is not updated.