# .NET CalDAV Client

Tags: .net, client, webdav, icalendar, caldav

I need my .NET application to access content from a variety of CalDAV servers. I have been looking for a good .NET CalDAV client library for a while now, but have been unable to find anything that suits my needs. Does such a library even exist, or is it something that I will need to write from scratch? I'm looking for something like on the iPhone where only a server address, username, and password are required.

Comment: The client library DDay.iCal states it supports RFC 5545  but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809534/creating-a-caldav-service-with-net) it may also support [CalDAV RFC4791 - Calendaring Extensions to WebDAV](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4791). But AFAICT based on the documentation it provides no methods to connect to a CalDav Server.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a [java implementation he might find it in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671120/is-there-a-java-caldav-api)

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: DDay.iCal is a library to read and write iCalendar files, not to do the DAV.

Answer (score -2):

You can check [this url](http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/caldav-library-net-framework). i hope this library  helps you

As requested:
This Client Library is provided for convenience to allow CardDAV/CalDAV connectivity within Microsoft Visual Studio projects. It is an abstraction Library that provides simple CalDAV / CardDAV connectivity.

The library also includes a primitive interface for parsing Calendar and Contact properties; although this is provided as a stub only (an implementation would involve sourcing a comprehensive parser of VCALENDAR and VCARDs).

Note: this is the license component for enterprise or if using for business purpose

Further details can be found @ http://www.arpdev.com/CalDAV_CardDAV_library.aspx

Comment: Please add some relevant information about the suggested resource and not just a link.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I'll keep a note of it from next time

Comment: ...You might want to fix the link in the first sentence.